# Very Odd Related List Behavior

Tags: permissions, page-layout, related-list

I have a very odd issue that I think must just be due to some interface setting that I am overlooking, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I have two users in an org, they both have the same role and profile.  I can't find anything different in their settings or permissions.

When one user looks at the activity history related list on a Contact they see the 5+ with a link to see all the activities in a list view

[image]

The other user looks at the same related list on the same contact and they don't have this link, but instead has all of the activities show up on the page by default, and in some cases makes the page fairly long.

I feel silly even asking because it seems like such a simple thing and I'm sure this is just some UI setting or checkbox that I am missing, but I just can't find it.  Am I missing something really simple here???  Has the user done something with there personal customization's?  I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user can control the amount of records displayed in related lists.

[How to show more/fewer records per related list - Default User Setting?](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005068&language=en_US)

> When viewing a Record Detail page (e.g. Account Detail) the related
>   lists shows a limited number of related records at a time. The number
>   of related records displayed on a Record Detail page can be increased
>   or decreased by default using the "more" or "fewer" link at the bottom
>   of the Record Detail page in the statement "Always show me more/fewer
>   records per related list". Clicking more or fewer increases and
>   decreases the default number of related list records displayed for all
>   object Record Detail pages for the logged in user.

Comment: I knew it was something I'd be embarrassed I missed!!  Awesome.  You answetred so quick I can't even acccept the answer yet.  Thanks a million @JesseAltman  I owe you a beer

Comment: @Dunc44 when you planning to owe a beer to Jesse?Dreamforce??

Comment: Sure.  First beer is on me at Dreamforce